# Component does not create dynamically to div specified using ViewChild in Angular

Tags: angular, angular8, viewchild, angular-dynamic-components

I'm trying to append/create into a specific div a component. However, the component is being created but not where I would like it to be. What I'm doing wrong?

[image]

I would like the k-sidebar component to be inside the div I'm showing into the image.

Below is my code.

App.component

```
 import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy, ViewChild, ElementRef, Renderer2, ViewContainerRef, 
 ComponentFactoryResolver, ComponentRef, ComponentFactory} from '@angular/core';
 @Component({
  selector: 'app-comp',
  templateUrl: './app-comp.component.html',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
 })
 export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  componentRef: any;
  @ViewChild('dynamicSidebar', {read: ViewContainerRef})
  public dynamicSidebar: ViewContainerRef;

  constructor(private factoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
   private containerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
   this.createSidebarComp();
 }


 createSidebarComp(){
  this.containerRef.clear();
  this.containerRef.createComponent(this.factoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(KSideBarComponent));
 }
}
```

HTML

```
<!-- header test -->
<k-header [navItems]="navItems" [title]="title">
 <ng-template rightSection>
 <k-icon [icon]="testIcon"></k-icon>
</ng-template>
</k-header>
<!-- /header test -->

<div class="container-fluid">
 <div #dynamicSidebar></div>
 <h1>{{title}} app is running!</h1>
 <router-outlet></router-outlet>

</div>
```

The sidebar is inside the router-outlet, and I would like to create the component above the h1 tag based on a boolean. What I`m doing wrong?

Comment: you created the component. where did you attach it to the dynamic side bar?

Comment: I would like to create the component inside the div I'm showing..which is in the app-root->container-fluid->div

Answer (score 0):

You can do

```
createSideBarComp() {
     this.dynamicSidebar.createComponent(this.factoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(KSideBarComponent));
}
```

the problem is you are not attaching to the sidebar reference you have taken (dynamicSideBar). But you are trying to attach to a viewContainerRef injected for the component through the constructor. This is not where you want to create the component.